# Return Address Manipulation does not work

Tags: assembly, stack

So my goal is to change the return address to skip the one byte 0xE8.
The return address is at the top of the stack after calling this function, right? So poping, add 1 and pushing the value should do the job.
At least it looks like that at first sight using OllyDbg, but in fact the rest of the code - just printing a string - wont work.

```
call    manipulate
db      0xE8

push    NULL
push    dummy
push    msg.len
push    msg
push    eax
call    WriteConsoleA 
push    NULL
call    ExitProcess

manipulate:
pop     eax
add     eax, 1
push    eax
ret
```

So why does this not work? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: your code and thinking seems right. maybe your printing call is broken? :) try without calling `manipulate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common routine is to store value of `BP register` in stack after procedure call. Then set `BP` to `top of stack`. After than you can access elements in stack using `BP`.

```
nameOfProc proc
           push BP
           mov  BP,SP
```

stack than looks like this:

```
ret address  |
BP register  | <-- BP / SP
```

Then you can access ret addres using `BP register` like this:

```
mov eax, [BP+4]
add eax, 1
mov [BP+4], eax
```

It is also fine to mark place where you want to return after procedure ends like

```
returnHere: some code
```

and than you can just simply do this:

```
mov [BP+4], offset returnHere
```

At the end you have to pop out `stored BP register` like this

```
           mov SP, BP
           pop BP
           ret  ;if you use some arguments for procedure - you push them to stack before call than use ret numberOfBytesOfAllArguments 
nameOfProc proc
```

I don't also understand `manipulate:` - this is not procedure but you call it with `call manipulate`.

Comment: you don't need mark code as procedure to `call` it. Any label or address is callable. Also op does not uses procedure macros so he doesn't have any `bp` changes in `manipulate`

Comment: Thank you for that much effort you put in answering that question! I'm sure that will help

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Yes you're right, my fault. Anyway I hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

Your call to `manipulate` thrashes the value inside `eax`, which is then used as an argument to `WriteConsoleA`.